# Finding all submodules of G-modules

Tags: representation-theory

Let V; W be irreducible G-modules that are not isomorphic to each other.
How to prove that the only G-submodules of M:= $V \oplus W$, other than $0$ and M itself, are $V =
V \oplus  0$
and $W =
0 \oplus W.$

Comment: Hint: Show that if a submodule is not of either of those forms, then it is isomorphic to both $V$ and $W$.

Comment: If we use that the  decomposition of any G-module into its isotypical component is unique, upto permutations, then the result is obvious. Isn`t it?

Comment: @user4567: Yes!  That's a great way of viewing the problem.  In fact it's what I thought when I first read the question but worried that this perspective might be too advanced.  The uniqueness of the isotypic decomposition is arguably underemphasized in many treatments of the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be any ring, and let $M$ be any semisimple left $R$-module.  Let $\{S_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a set of representatives for the isomorphism classes of simple left $R$-modules.  For each $i \in I$, let $M_i$ be the direct sum of all simple submodules isomorphic to $S_i$, the **$\bf{S_i}$-isotypic component of M**.  It is immediate that $M = \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i$: this is the **isotypic decomposition** of $M$.  Note that no choices have been made: this decomposition is unique.

(What is not completely obvious is that the number of independent copies of $S_i$ in $M_i$ is a well-defined invariant of $M$.  If $M$ is finitely generated this follows from the Jordan-Holder Theorem.  In the general case see $\S$ 2.3 of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/noncommutativealgebra.pdf).  But this is not needed in what follows.)

Now let $N$ be a submodule of $M$.  Then $N_i$, the $S_i$-isotypic component of $N$, is $N \cap M_i$: both are the direct sum of all simple submodules of $N$ isomorphic to $S_i$.

In the case that $M = S_1 \oplus S_2$ is a direct sum of two nonisomorphic simple modules, we get immediately that $N = (S_1 \cap N) \oplus (S_2 \cap N)$.  Since $S_1$ and $S_2$ each have exactly two submodules, this shows that the obvious submodules $0$, $S_1 \oplus 0$, $S_2 \oplus 0$, $S_1 \oplus S_2$ are indeed the only four submodules of $M$.

There is an evident generalization to semisimple modules each of whose isotypic components is simple.

Answer (score 3):

Pete's emphasis on isotypic components is a much better idea long term. Here is the "other" proof, for reference.

Suppose $M$ is a direct sum of two simple modules $V$ and $W$.

$N \cap V$ is a submodule of $V$, so either it is $V$ and $V \leq N$, or it is $0$ and so $N+V$ is a direct sum. In the first case, consider $N/V \leq M/V \cong W$. Since $W$ is simple, either $N=M$ or $N=V$. In the second case $(N \oplus V)/V \leq M/V \cong W$, a simple module, so either $N \oplus V = V$ (so $N=0$) or $N \oplus V = M$.

In this last case, $N \oplus V=M$ we need to consider $N \cap W$ as well. As before, we get one of $N=0$ (no), $N=M$ (no), or $N=W$ (yes, but we consider the last as well), or $N\oplus W=M$.

In this last case of the last case, we get that $N \oplus V = N \oplus W = V \oplus W$, and so quotienting both sides by $N$, we get $V \cong W$.

Hence the only possibilities are: $N=0$, $N=V$, $N=W$, $N=M$, or $N \cong V \cong W$.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that V,W are irreducible G-modules.  Define M to be the direct sum of V and W.  A submodule of M has the form of a submodule of V direct sum a submodule of W.  By the assumptions that V and W are irreducible there are only two choices for each of V and W for what those submodules can be.

Comment: -1: "A submodule of M has the form of a submodule of V direct sum a submodule of W." This is false if $V \cong W$.  Consider the case of linear algebra! The point of the question is to correctly use the hypothesis that $V \not \cong W$.